# Are there other ways of implementing a visual web scraper besides loading the data inside a local iframe?

Tags: web-scraping, extract, screen-scraping

I saw the video for [Portia](https://scrapinghub.com/portia/) and I was thinking about how such a tool could be implemented. Basically, having a web app, where you would input an URL, it would load ( like if you would have loaded it in a standalone browser tab ), and then you would be able to click on elements in the page, and visually select the data you want to extract.

An idea I currently have is this:

1. retrieve website content using a headless browser
2. have a route in a webapp, that would serve the scraped content
3. embed the route in an iframe in the data selection page, to bypass same origin policy
4. integrate some JavaScript element inspector library, to be able to visually mark elements meant to be scraped
5. generate a set of selectors
6. use the selectors to extract data

I'm interested if there are/what other approaches to handle this, specifically parts 1 to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that the objects that you're going to want to scrape aren't probably active (e.g. they don't respond to clicks or keypresses).

Even if they do, they probably won't handle meta keys such as Ctrl or Shift.

So what you could do is to build your system exactly like a proxy, rewriting internal URLs (this you'd need to do regardless), *except* that you would also inject Javascript code to react to, say, click.

Then you would need no IFRAME, and simply navigate to `www.your-scraper.com`, request `www.site-to-scrape.com` in a form, get assigned a random `dab3b19f` and get redirected to `dab3b19f.your-scraper.com` -- and would see a version of `www.site-to-scrape.com` where all (text?) objects react to Ctrl-Click.

The user should then be able to move in the site normally, except that holding e.g. the Ctrl key while clicking would not pass the click to the clicked object, but to a handler that could then identify the event target and calculate its CSS path, then pop up a scraping menu in a fixed DIV appended to the DOM on demand, and removed on close.

This implies that you'd need to detect and hijack several possible Javascript libraries that the site might be loading. If the thing goes on, possibly you would also need to defang some anti-scraping code (e.g. the site might check DOM integrity or try to rewrite handlers to default states).

At the same time, you could also intercept and record the *normal* clicks in order to be able to duplicate, up to a point (it depends on how dynamic the site is, and how you can interact with your headless browser). This would allow you to automatically re-navigate the site, changing pages etc., to reach the various objects. You would then end up with a series of selectors and navigational hints that could be used to extract data from the navigated pages:

```
start
click        #menu ul[2] li[1] span
click        .right.sidebar[1] ul[1] li[5] input[type="checkbox"]
click        .right.sidebar[1] ul[1] li[5] button
scrape(TICK) #prices div div[2] div div span p
scrape(PRIC) #prices div div[2] div div span div span[2] p
```

The scraping script could then be modified to add, say, loops. This comes later, though.

You would also end up with something not too unlike [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). In fact you might want to consider the possibility of [turning Selenium to your purpose](http://thiagomarzagao.com/2013/11/12/webscraping-with-selenium-part-1/).

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the full answer to the question, but to share my experience with that.

On one of the projects I've participated in, we had a *Chrome browser extension* that allowed to pinpoint/select the elements visually on a page, give them "names" and save (we called that process "annotation"), which led to a record being created in the database that contained a target site URL, field name and a generated CSS selector or an XPath expression.

The extension was based on the [`selectorgadget` library](http://selectorgadget.com/).

From what I remember, the generated locators were either absolute (started from the very `html` or `body` root), or could only use `id` attributes of the element or one of parent elements - similar to how the "Copy XPath" and "Copy CSS Path" tools work in FireBug.

Then, we had a very broad [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) spider that used the prepared annotations in the database to scrape any website. Well, that would be too good and easy to be true. Of course, we had to add custom code to tackle heavy-dynamic web pages, bot detections, flakiness and different web-site specific logic.

<sub>(will improve the answer more).</sub>

Comment: Thanks alecxe, do you have any thoughts on handling this without having users install the chrome extension? What do you think about the iframe approach I mentioned? I was hoping with that + some javascript element inspector library to achieve something similar to what chrome inspector is doing. Not all the functionality of course, just visually selecting an element and getting a css/xpath selector from it.

Comment: @Geo that might work - sort of a "mini-browser" inside the browser which has additional capabilities to select and annotate elements. By the way, I've found some old version of the extension and can provide more details if needed - it is based on the [`selectorgadget` library](http://selectorgadget.com/) - kind of old, but looks quite related to what you are working on. May be there is a better/newer alternative to it.